# TypeScript fundamentals: generics and arrow functions

Tags: typescript, generics, arrow-functions

I was going through the TypeScript handbook and was attempting to convert the following:

```
function map<Input, Output>(
  arr: Input[],
  func: (arg: Input) => Output
): Output[] {
  return arr.map(func);
}
```

to an arrow function. So I did this, which I think is correct:

```
const map2 = <Input, Output>(
  arr: Input[],
  func: (arg: Input) => Output
): Output[] => {
  return arr.map(func);
};
```

But I was wondering how I'd implement it if I wanted to use a type alias for the function like this:

```
type Fn = <X, Y>(x: X) => Y;
const map2 = <Input, Output>(
  arr: Input[],
  func: Fn 
): Output[] => {
  return arr.map(func);
};
```

This example above yields an error because of Output[]. So how would I define the output type of `map2` since `Output[]` will no longer work? Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking how you should define your type alias so that you can use it as the type for `func` in the `map2`?

Comment: @Olian04 I edited the original post slightly. Let me know if that helps explain the question better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use `Fn` in the exact way you've described, we need to define `Fn` in such a way that allows us to pass in our generics when we use the type. Like this:

```
type Fn<X, Y> = (x: X) => Y;

const map2 = <Input, Output>(
  arr: Input[],
  func: Fn<Input, Output>
): Output[] => {
  return arr.map(func);
};
```